# Service similar to Airbrake.io for java applications?

Tags: java, error-handling, airbrake

We made our own api for [airbrake.io](http://www.airbrake.io) in java. This works fine but airbrake is displaying parameters and stacktraces in some kind of Rails style. This is somewhat annoying. Anyone know of similar services made for java?

Example of how data is displayed:

**Parameters**

```
{"controller"=>"", "action"=>""}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
/testapp/app/models/user.rb:53:in `public'
/testapp/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `index'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 2015-02-13:** This service no longer exists.  The GitHub account linked below is gone, as is the company website.

<strike>Have you tried using Coalmine https://github.com/coalmine/coalmine_java Its meant to be used with the Coalmine service: https://getcoalmine.com/</strike>

I work at Coalmine and we have been using this internally for some time now. We just open sourced the java connector this week and I would be happy to help you get started with it. You can send me an email at brad@builtfromsource.com

Comment: Yep, Coalmine shutdown some time ago. I now recommend Sentry: https://getsentry.com/welcome/ or New Relic: http://newrelic.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using http://code.google.com/p/hoptoad/ . It's a little out of date, but it should just need to update an endpoint to http://api.airbrake.io .

A quick google lead me to http://logdigger.com/ which is designed specific for JAVA specific sites.

I work at Airbrake, and I would be happy to work with you to make our site more JAVA friendly.   Please get in touch ben@airbrake.io, and I'll see how we can better display java specific information.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the others suggested here, but Raygun (http://raygun.io) has first class support for Java.

Read more here: http://raygun.io/java

I work for Mindscape who built Raygun so can answer any questions you may have about it: jd@mindscape.co.nz. We already have a large number of organizations using Raygun with their Java apps, although Raygun does support other platforms (.NET, Node, Rails, PHP, etc)